# JTextArea after pressed enter

Tags: java, swing, sockets, jtextarea, caret

I am creating a chat for java using sockets. My problem is that on the frame for the user when i hit enter for the first time the Caret goes to the next line and everything after that i have to press backspace because otherwise a blank sentence is sent with the sentence I wrote. I use a KeyListener for pressing enter and I have enter the following code to the keyPressed function.

```
    if(arg0.getKeyCode()==10)
    {
        System.out.println("Bika sto enter\n");
        String toserver = ClientText.text2.getText();

        try {
            if(toserver.equals("close it")) {
                ClientText.clientSocket.close(); 
            }



            ClientText.text2.moveCaretPosition(ClientText.text2.getSelectionStart());
            ClientText.text2.setCaretPosition(0);
            ClientText.text2.setText("");
            ClientText.outToServer.writeBytes(toserver+'\n');
            //ClientText.outToServer.writeUTF(toserver+'\n');
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The thing is that this works only after the first time I use the chat. For example I sent something and the caret goes to the next line if i press Enter. Then if i write something and press enter the caret goes to the beggining of the second line! Therefore there is an empty first line i have to erase every time any help on this one? Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2162974/1428683 I found the answer at this post actually after a bit research.

Comment: Why not post the relevant part of that answer, and provide your own answer, and mark it correct, which will be a good idea, as it will help future visitors too (though don't delete that link from this answer, that way this link will remain active, on the right side of this page, under __Linked__ Category). Else you can delete this post, which in my opinion is not a good thingy to do now :-)

Comment: i suggest also to have a look ad some kind of chat protocol.. try this http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1459.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what your GUI looks like, but I would use javax.swing.JTextField instead of JTextArea. If you want to use a JTextArea (for example to allow multiple-line messages) and you can't get the enter-to-send part to work, I would resort to using the KeyListener as the key input, like a normal computer (if all else fails).

This is what I mean:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JTextArea; //or JTextField
public class KeyInput implements KeyListener{
    private JTextArea ta; //or JTextField
    public KeyInput(JTextArea ta){ //or JTextField
        this.ta = ta;
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
            //code to send message goes here
        }else{
            ta.append("\n"+e.getKeyChar());
        }
    }
//keyReleased(KeyEvent) and keyTyped(KeyEvent) methods go here, need no content
}
```

Remember, if you use a JTextArea, make sure to put it in a JScrollPane.
**IMPORTANT**: in your client class, make sure you add `ta.setEditable(false)` in which ta is the variable name of your JTextArea (again, can be substituted for a JTextField in which case you don't need JScrollPane).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I probably should have asked earlier, but can anyone explain the upvote and the almost instantaneous following downvote?